# Inserir várias linhas no Informix

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-insert, informix, ansi

Uso um banco Informix e tenho que fazer 3500 inserts. O Informix executa linha a linha e isso é impraticável. Como faço para inserir todas as linhas de uma vez?
Exemplo:

```
insert into tabela (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3) values (valor1, valor2, valor3)
insert into tabela (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3) values (valorn, valorm, valorx)
```

Preciso executar esses inserts simultaneamente.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
INSERT INTO tb_tabela (coluna1, coluna2, coluna3)
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT valor1, valor2, valor3 FROM SYSMASTER:SYSDUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT valorn, valorm, valorx FROM SYSMASTER:SYSDUAL
)

MERGE INTO tb_tabela AS tab
USING
(
SELECT valor1 as coluna1, valor2 as coluna2, valor3 as coluna3 FROM SYSMASTER:SYSDUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT valorn as coluna1, valorm as coluna2, valorx as coluna3 FROM SYSMASTER:SYSDUAL
)   AS query 
ON tab.id = query.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tab.coluna1 = query.coluna1, tab.coluna2 = query.coluna2, tab.coluna3 = query.coluna3
```

Comment: Apesar de achar um tanto mirabolante sua solução, gostaria de entender porque tecnicamente ela atende sua necessidade e a sequencia de inserts não ? Performance?

Comment: Performance. Sequencia de insert fará linha a linha, dessa forma "mirabolante" é feita em bloco.

Comment: Para considerar o envio tudo em um unico bloco realmente é uma solução já que o Informix não tem uma solução acessivel via SQL. Mas tem recursos para quando se trabalha com insert que são buffers para quando é usado o PUT, mas ai você precisa estudar a linguagem de programação que está usando para garantir esse uso, veja estes dois links : [para jdbc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_089.htm) , [testes gerais de performance](http://www.imartins.com.br/informix/artigos/testes-praticos-performance-com-fetbufsize-opcao-b-sqlhosts)

Comment: faltou mais esse link do [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.odbc.doc/ids_odbc_219.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente o Informix não possui um comando DML para `insert` em modo *batch/bulk* como no mysql .

As opções de carga em batch são a partir de arquivo TXT utilizando delimitadores (que por padrão, no Informix é o pipe "|" mas pode usar outros, como ";" usado no padrão CSV).
Todas estas opções, normalmente o arquivo TXT tem que estar acessível pelo servidor onde roda o banco de dados, pois é dele que será feito o acesso ao arquivo (mesmo no caso do *external table*).

- EXTERNAL TABLE
  Onde você pode criar uma tabela que irá ler o TXT diretamente e assim fazer um `insert into ... select * from ...`
- LOAD
  Porém é suportado apenas no utilitário `dbaccess` que é uma versão CUI e normalmente executado apenas no servidor. Apesar de ter alguma versão do client, não me lembro qual, que ele também vem instalado.
- DBLOAD
  Utilitário para carga de dados com controle de transação. 
  Também disponível apenas no servidor.
- HPL
  Utilitário pra carga de dados em alta performance. Util apenas se você precisa carregar milhões de linhas.
  Também disponível apenas no servidor.

Sei que no JDBC e ODBC existem funções para "bulk insert", mas entendo que deverá ser especificamente programado em seu código e tem por objetivo agilizar a performance do processo de carga e não facilitar a sua vida.

Você pode consultar estes comandos no manual online do produto em [Informix 12.10 knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm)

Se esta carga será feita apenas uma unica vez, você pode usar programas cliente SQL para te auxiliar, como o [SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net) . Ele possui um [plugin](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins) chamado "dataimport" que permite carregar em uma tabela dados de arquivos Excel ou no formato CSV .

> This plugin adds the ability to import data from Excel or CSV files
>   into a database using SQuirreL.